# Transfer file using MSTSC in Command line

Tags: c#, cmd, mstsc

Part of my daily work involves transferring of data from my system to client system using MSTSC, is it possible to automate this transfer or is there any command line that i can use instead of connecting to the Jumpbox and then manually moving the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [command line switch](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-command-line-parameters-with-Remote-Desktop-Connection) or [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383552%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to let you to access the remote session.

You can write a file server (e.g. FTP) or a [virtual channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383546%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to transfer the files.

Answer (score 5):

You said 'jump box' so I'm assuming you need to connect to your jump server and then start your rdp session.

How are you copying the files once you logon to the remote server? Drag and drop (copy/paste) via Explorer? If so this can be hideously slow through a jump server. It's best to use a command line copy utility and the \tsclient mappings.

**`robocopy \\tsclient\C\somefolder C:\temp *.exe`** or whatever. Unfortunately this is all predicated on establishing the remote desktop session first so there is no way I'm aware of to initiate a copy from your local workstation to the remote host using a jump server.

One thing we're trying to do is to get our security people to allow firewall rules into our secured zones so we can automate BITS to do the copies for us.

Comment: This is exactly what i do except robocopy, i want to totally automate logging and then copying the data..

Comment: Unfortunately, jump servers make automation virtually impossible because you have no direct access to the remote server(s). As I mentioned, we're trying to get the gods of security to allow us to open a couple of ports just for BITS. WinRM would also be an option but they won't let us have any type of logon session directly through a secured firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You can use freerdp or rdesktop Linux aplications (for example under virtual server environment if you have not one already) to map remote dirs on local pathes and then copy to it.

There also tool for windows - http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/System/tsdc/Freeware.htm but I had not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a Scheduled Task?  I'll generally try and use a batch file or something simple, or you can use robocopy etc.

Comment: Sorry i have not used Robocopy, does it support connecting to remote machines, logging in and then copying data?